# write query for fetch data for same customer_id and submmited_by but additional cases

Tags: mysql

I Wrote query for fetch same data

```
    select *,
 row_number() over(partition by customer_id,submitted_by order by date_created ASC) as row_num from defaulters 
where submitted_by in (
  select submitted_by from (
     select count(id) as count, customer_id,submitted_by
    FROM
    defaulters
    group by customer_id,submitted_by
    having count > 1
    ) as defaulters
) and customer_id in (
  select customer_id from (
     select count(id) as count, customer_id,submitted_by
    FROM
    defaulters
    group by customer_id,submitted_by
    having count > 1
    ) as defaulters
)
limit 0,10
```

I get the data successfully

[image]

but i could not solve some cases:-

1. I want those records in which the defaulters_status of the first row is not 'rejected' only for same customer_id and submitted_by.

And how do i optimize my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Do not use `IN ( SELECT ... )`.  Instead use `JOIN ( SELECT ... ) ON ...`
- A `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` may lead to unexpected rows being returned.
- The two inner queries look very similar; see if you can combine them.
- This would probably help: `INDEX(customer_id, submitted_by)`